# Read excel and get data of 1 row as a object

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a excel file using pandas and want row of the excel as object like

```
{2, 3,'test data' , 1}
```

I am reading pandas file like

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel(upload_file_url , index_col=None, header=None)
for name in excel_data:
    print(name)
```

but on printing I am getting just plan text . how I can achieve this with pandas ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: @MattDMo sir I have posted what I have tried already . and expected output also mentioned .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iterrows()` method might help to get individual rows from the dataframe.

Consider the following crude solution

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel(upload_file_url , index_col=None, header=None)
for name in excel_data.iterrows():
    print(str(name[1].tolist()).replace("[","{").replace("]","}"))
```

Here we use `iterrows()` to get individual rows of the spreadsheet as tuples.
Each tuple contains the row data at position 1 as Pandas Series.

In order to convert Pandas Series to `{2, 3,'test data' , 1}` you might just convert it to list and replace square brackets with curly brackets.

**Update:** If you could print the data as dict instead of a list in curly brackets, the code would be simplified.

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel(upload_file_url , index_col=None, header=None)
for name in excel_data.iterrows():
    print(name[1].to_dict())
```

Comment: hi thanks sir for replying . working fine only issue on list step . can't I use todist() etc instead of tolist ? I need at the end object of array of all excel file

Comment: sure, you could use `print(name[1].to_dict())` instead. However the output format would be different from what you put as an example of your desired output.

Comment: sir thank you so much . working like charm